# Are patient years or per patient per year the standard unit of measurement

Tags: health-economics

For the assessment for excess cost of a condition over a control group is it correct to use patient years or per patient per year?

The use case is demonstrating the cost burden of hospitalisation for one condition over healthy controls.

I have data from patients on the number of hospitalisations of persons with a rare disease, and hospitalisation in an age matched cohort.

So hospitalisations can be calculated for patient years or per patient per year. I have always calculated this per patient year, whereas the analysts have calculated it per patient per year, which is what they are used to doing. I am wondering whether which is correct.

The two different methods give different results as spelled out below:

Hospitalisations/Patient years = total number of hospitalisations in all patients/total amount of follow up in years for all patients

OR

Hospitalisations Per patient per year = (hospitalisations for person A/follow up in years) + (hospitalisations for person B/follow up in years)/number of people

I am wondering which one is correct for the use case of demonstrating the cost of a condition?

edit: clarified and provided more specific information

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: clarified the above and provided more specific information